# Moving from pdfLatex to LuaLatex makes my titles bold

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex, titles

I want to switch to LuaLatex from pdfLatex. My only problem right now, it makes all my titles bold, I want them 'thinner' again.

So, here's how it looked with pdfLatex before the switch:

[image: pdfLatex]

And this is how it looks now, with LuaLatex:

[image: LuaLatex]

I didn't change anything except the compiler.
I'm using the `scrbook` document class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: pdflatex and lualatex should give the same output for the common cases.  It looks like you're doing some sort of font transformation that works in one but not the other.  But without seeing your code, we can just offer blind guesses.  But you should be able to trim what you're doing down to 10 lines or so.

Comment: Another possibility is that pdflatex and lualatex are choosing different fonts. But I think @Teepeemm has the right idea.